# iReport 3.7.4 Creating Hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink, jasper-reports

I am trying to create a hyper link to another report and pass some parameters in the process. I was working on the actual copy but I couldn't make it work so I decided to start from basic which involves only opening a new report via link.

Here is what I do:

Set target = self (irrelevant, I guess)

Set type = reference

First, I add following link parameter:

_report, "Report2"

Report2 is located in same folder with Report1 which is the report that I am trying to invoke report2 but it doesn't work. I also tried setting type to report execution but that didn't work as well. I don't know what reference tab is doing but I tried to put some path to there as well but it didn't work either. How can I open a new report with hyper link and pass some parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to follow the implementation guide for Custom Hyperlinks http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/hyperlink/ and http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/view/JRHyperlinkListener.html